# Using Realm and LiveData. Converting LiveData<RealmResults<CustomModelObject>> to LiveData<List<CustomModelObject>>

Tags: android, realm, android-livedata

I am trying out Realm along with Android architecture components including LiveData.

I have been following Google's Guide to Application Architecture:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

...substituting Room with Realm.

I have everything working using:

```
LiveData<RealmResults<CustomModelObject>>
```

from my repository layer right through ViewModel to View.

I am thinking it might be nicer to only have more generic types coming back from repository so `LiveData<List<CustomModelObject>>` rather than `LiveData<RealmResults<CustomModelObject>>`.

Here is a code snippet of where I have got stuck:

```
@NonNull
@Override
protected LiveData<List<CustomModelObject>> loadFromDb() {
    return Transformations.switchMap(customModelObjectsDao.getCustomModelObjects(),
        new Function<RealmResults<CustomModelObject>, LiveData<List<CustomModelObject>>>() {
        @Override
        public LiveData<List<CustomModelObject>> apply(RealmResults<CustomModelObject> data) {
            if (data == null) {
                return AbsentLiveData.create();
            } else {
                return customModelObjectsDao.getCustomModelObjects();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`customModelObjectsDao.getCustomModelObjects()` currently returns `LiveData<RealmResults<Inspiration>>`.

I want to transform it to `LiveData<List<Inspiration>>`.

I have tried various `Transformations.map` and `Transformations.switchMap` etc with no success and I think I have been staring at it too long now :)

Am I on the right path or am I missing something obvious?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul.

**UPDATE**

DAO:

```
public RealmLiveData<CustomModelObject> getCustomModelObjects() {
    return asLiveData(realm.where(CustomModelObject.class).findAllAsync());
}
```

asLiveData Impl:

```
fun <T: RealmModel> RealmResults<T>.asLiveData() = RealmLiveData<T>(this)
fun Realm.CustomModelObjectsDao(): CustomModelObjectsDao = CustomModelObjectsDao(this)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
public class RealmLiveData<T> extends LiveData<RealmResults<T>> {

private RealmResults<T> results;

private final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> listener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<T> results) {
        setValue(results);
    }
};

public RealmLiveData(RealmResults<T> realmResults) {
    results = realmResults;
}

@Override
protected void onActive() {
    results.addChangeListener(listener);
}

@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    results.removeChangeListener(listener);
}
}
```

Comment: I need to know how your DAO works to answer this (`customModelObjectsDao.getCustomModelObjects()`)

Comment: Hi Epic, I have updated the question. Thanks, Paul.

Comment: Welp, now I need to ask if `RealmLiveData` is custom, or [from the `realm-examples`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/b7b33ceb3e9e6782accd7f608e8956ea646903a0/examples/architectureComponentsExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/arch/livemodel/LiveRealmResults.java) :D but I think you'll also need to add `RealmLIveData` to the question for it to be complete

Comment: Ha! I thought that was coming :) It is pretty much the same with less error handling. Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case, replacing `LiveData<RealmResults<T>` with `LiveData<List<T>>` would be enough to solve your problem.

However, I'd advise trying out the `RealmLiveResults` class that is available in [the official example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/b7b33ceb3e9e6782accd7f608e8956ea646903a0/examples/architectureComponentsExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/arch/livemodel/LiveRealmResults.java):

```
/**
 * This class represents a RealmResults wrapped inside a LiveData.
 *
 * Realm will always keep the RealmResults up-to-date whenever a change occurs on any thread,
 * and when that happens, the observer will be notified.
 *
 * The RealmResults will be observed until it is invalidated - meaning all local Realm instances on this thread are closed.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of the RealmModel
 */
public class LiveRealmResults<T extends RealmModel> extends LiveData<List<T>> {
    private final RealmResults<T> results;

    // The listener will notify the observers whenever a change occurs.
    // The results are modified in change. This could be expanded to also return the change set in a pair.
    private OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> listener = new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(@NonNull RealmResults<T> results, @Nullable OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
            LiveRealmResults.this.setValue(results);
        }
    };

    @MainThread
    public LiveRealmResults(@NonNull RealmResults<T> results) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (results == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Results cannot be null!");
        }
        if (!results.isValid()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The provided RealmResults is no longer valid, the Realm instance it belongs to is closed. It can no longer be observed for changes.");
        }
        this.results = results;
        if (results.isLoaded()) {
            // we should not notify observers when results aren't ready yet (async query).
            // however, synchronous query should be set explicitly.
            setValue(results);
        }
    }

    // We should start observing and stop observing, depending on whether we have observers.

    /**
     * Starts observing the RealmResults, if it is still valid.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        if (results.isValid()) { // invalidated results can no longer be observed.
            results.addChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stops observing the RealmResults.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        if (results.isValid()) {
            results.removeChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

This way your `dao` can expose `LiveData<List<T>>`, and your `Transformations.map()` should work.

Comment: I'm such a noob :) You've been such a great help thnx so much! I tried your first suggestion and it worked instantly. I will also take your advice and use the livedata wrapper from the official example. Cheers, Paul.

Comment: I've heard some people say that in `onActive()`, a `setValue(results)` call is missing. I can't verify nor refute this claim. I don't think it *should*, assuming you are using `observe` and then results changes in place anyway, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

If you need:

```
val list : LiveData<List<mRealmObject>>
```

First: Create this file:

```
class RealmLiveData<T : RealmModel>(private val results: RealmResults<T>) :
  LiveData<RealmResults<T>>() {
  private val listener: RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> =
    RealmChangeListener { results -> value = results }

  override fun onActive() {
    results.addChangeListener(listener)
  }

  override fun onInactive() {
    results.removeChangeListener(listener)
  }
}

fun <T: RealmModel> RealmResults<T>.asLiveData() = RealmLiveData<T>(this)
```

Second: Get your new RealmLiveData :

```
val mRealmLiveData = realm.where(mRealmObject::class.java).findAllAsync().asLiveData()
```

And Finally, get the list you need like this:

```
val list: LiveData<List<mRealmObject>> = Transformations.map(mRealmLiveData) {
  realmResult ->
    realm.copyFromRealm(realmResult)
  }
```

If you use it in a ViewModel:

```
//get realm instance   
val realm: Realm by lazy {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    }
// get your live data
val list: LiveData<List<mRealmObject>> = Transformations.map(mRealmLiveData) {
  realmResult ->
    realm.copyFromRealm(realmResult)
  }
// Close your realm instance onCleraded
override fun onCleared() {
  realm.close()
  super.onCleared()
  }
```