# Unit testing Realm wrapped LiveData with Mockito

Tags: android, realm, mockito, android-livedata

I am trying out Realm along with Android architecture components including LiveData.

I have been following Google's Guide to Application Architecture:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

...substituting Room with Realm.

I have everything working from an implementation perspective but have run into an issue with Mockito I cannot yet resolve when trying to write unit tests.

I have shown my test below with some commented out lines along with explanations of what I have tried so far and the result:

```
@Test
public void loadCustomModelObjectsFromNetwork() throws IOException {

    // Prepare DAO
    MutableLiveData<List<CustomModelObject>> dbData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    // Compilation error
    //when(dao.getCustomModelObjects()).thenReturn(dbData);

    // Runtime exc.
    //doReturn(dbData).when(dao).getCustomModelObjects();

    // Runtime exc.
    //java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    //android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData cannot be cast to LiveRealmResults
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock i) throws Throwable {
            // Made various attempts to convert to LiveRealmResults here 
            return dbData;
        }
    }).when(dao).getCustomModelObjects();

/*
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
MutableLiveData cannot be returned by getCustomModelObjectss()
getCustomModelObjects() should return LiveRealmResults
*/

    // Prepare REST service response
    List<CustomModelObject> customModelObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    CustomModelObject repo = new CustomModelObject();
    repo.setDescription("Desc1");
    customModelObjects.add(repo);

    CustomModelObjectsResponse response = new CustomModelObjectsResponse();
    response.setCustomModelObjects(customModelObjects);

    DocumentWrapper<CustomModelObjectsResponse> items = new DocumentWrapper<>();
    items.setBody(response);

    LiveData<ApiResponse<DocumentWrapper<CustomModelObjectsResponse>>> call = successCall(items);
    when(retrofitService.getCustomModelObjects()).thenReturn(call);
    when(service.getService()).thenReturn(retrofitService);

    // Item under test
    LiveData<Resource<List<CustomModelObject>>> data = repository.getCustomModelObjects();

    // Assertions
    verify(dao).getCustomModelObjects();

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(service);

    Observer observer = mock(Observer.class);
    data.observeForever(observer);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(service);
    verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.loading(null));

    MutableLiveData<List<CustomModelObject>> updatedDbData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    //when(dao.getCustomModelObjects()).thenReturn(updatedDbData);
    doReturn(updatedDbData).when(dao).getCustomModelObjects();

    dbData.postValue(null);
    verify(retrofitService).getCustomModelObjects();
    verify(dao).save(customModelObjects);

    updatedDbData.postValue(customModelObjects);
    verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.success(repo));
}
```

Even though in my implementation it works fine and `LiveData<List<CustomModelObject>>` can be derived from `LiveRealmResults<CustomModelObject>` in the unit test I cannot seem to get this to work with Mockito.

More implementation details about my setup can be found here:

[Using Realm and LiveData. Converting LiveData<RealmResults<CustomModelObject>> to LiveData<List<CustomModelObject>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654211/using-realm-and-livedata-converting-livedatarealmresultscustommodelobject-t)

Thanks,
Paul.

**UPDATE**

```
when(dao.getCustomModelObjects()).thenReturn(dbData);

has the following compilation error:

error: no suitable method found for 

thenReturn(MutableLiveData<List<CustomModelObject>>)
method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(LiveRealmResults<CustomModelObject>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MutableLiveData<List<CustomModelObject>> cannot be converted to LiveRealmResults<CustomModelObject>)
method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(LiveRealmResults<CustomModelObject>,LiveRealmResults<CustomModelObject>...) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MutableLiveData<List<CustomModelObject>> cannot be converted to LiveRealmResults<CustomModelObject>)
```

Comment: `when(dao.getCustomModelObjects()).thenReturn(dbData);` should work.

Comment: Hi Epic, I have tried this and I get a compilation error. I have updated the question with that error. Thanks.

Comment: It's because I'm trying to cast up incorrectly from 'MutableLiveData<List<CustomModelObject>> to LiveRealmResults<CustomModelObject>'. I will try mocking dbData.

Comment: You should see `LiveData<List<T>>` instead of `LiveRealmResults<T>` when you're trying to mock. The dao should return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public RealmLiveData<CustomModelObject> getCustomModelObjects() {
    return asLiveData(realm.where(CustomModelObject.class).findAllAsync());
}
```

should be

```
public LiveData<List<<CustomModelObject>> getCustomModelObjects() {
    return asLiveData(realm.where(CustomModelObject.class).findAllAsync());
}
```

Then your `when(...)` should no longer have compilation error.